# Did I understand RG correctly?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, renormalization

I am currently self-studying Renormalization Group (RG) in Condensed matter physics (in preparation for graduate school while I'm in Alternative Military Service).
While I'm writing bunch of mathmetical symbols, I just want to confirm whether I understood RG correctly or not (so that I could know if I'm wasting time).

What I understand about RG, is that a physical theory is dependent on a (length/momentum) scale that we address.

If we consider a Hamiltonian (or Lagrangian) in 1nm scale, the constants in the Hamiltonian (mass, charge, coupling constants, etc) are different from other scales and we can calculate the change of the constants when we change the scale

By this change of scale,

some constants (and the term) are negligible (since they decreases) => irrelevant.

some are not (since they increases) => relevant.

some don't change => marginal.

So we can view the theory in macroscopic scale without the microscopic detail of it.

Now, we can explain why two system, magnets and gas, show similar phenomenon, because the two theory has a different microscopic details in small scale, but in large (length) scale, by performing the RG procedure we could know that some of these details become negligible, remain, and therefore the two theory became similar(which means they are near the fixed points in coupling constant space).

Did I get it correct?

P.S. I'm non-english speaker so if there some uncomprehensible expression or something let me know it

Comment: _we can explain why two system, magnets and gas, show similar phenomenon_ What phenomenon exactly are you talking about ?

Comment: Agnius/ I am talking about critical properties in 2nd order phase transition like crtical exponents